# jQuery How to parse start and end time hour by hour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have issues, i working with time mode, and now i have two values is:

```
var startTime = "05:45:00 22/05/19"
var endTime = "14:45:00 22/05/19"
```

So problem is, i need to parse this date by hours.

Result must be:

```
05:45 - 06:00
06:00 - 07:00
07:00 - 08:00
08:00 - 09:00
09:00 - 10:00
10:00 - 11:00
11:00 - 12:00
12:00 - 13:00
13:00 - 14:00
14:00 - 14:45
```

As u can see i need not standart parsing hours.

So i try to use this method:

```
function addMinutes(time, minutes) {
    var date = new Date(new Date('01/01/2015 ' + time).getTime() + minutes * 60000);
    var tempTime = ((date.getHours().toString().length == 1) ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours()) + ':' +
        ((date.getMinutes().toString().length == 1) ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes()) + ':' +
        ((date.getSeconds().toString().length == 1) ? '0' + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds());
    return tempTime;
}

var starttime = "05:45:00";
var interval = "60";
var endtime = "14:45:00";
var timeslots = [starttime];


while (starttime != endtime) {

    starttime = addMinutes(starttime, interval);
    timeslots.push(starttime);

}
console.log(timeslots);
```

OUTPUT:

```
0: "05:45:00"
1: "06:45:00"
2: "07:45:00"
3: "08:45:00"
4: "09:45:00"
5: "10:45:00"
6: "11:45:00"
7: "12:45:00"
8: "13:45:00"
9: "14:45:00"
```

But for me it's not good, plus if end date is for next date it's not calculate

Comment: If it's an option, Moment or one of the other date/time libraries will serve you well in this capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution :
loop from start hour to end hour and check if we are on the first hour or end hour to do some specific code otherwise render startHour - startHour +1

```js
 var startTime = "15:00"
 var endTime = "00:15"
 var timeslots = [];
 
 
 var startOffset = parseInt(startTime.substring(0,2));
 var endOffset =  parseInt(endTime.substring(0,2));
 
 if(endOffset < startOffset){
  endOffset+= 24;
 }
 
 for(var i = startOffset;i<=endOffset;i++){
  var begin,end;
  var currentOffset = i < 24 ? i : i - 24;
  if(i==startOffset){
   begin = startTime;
  }else{
   begin = currentOffset < 10 ? "0" + currentOffset +":00" : currentOffset +":00" ;
  }
  if(i==endOffset){
   end = endTime;
  }else{
   
   end = currentOffset < 9 ? "0" + (currentOffset+1) +":00" :(currentOffset+1) +":00";
  }
  timeslots.push(begin + " : " + end);
 }
 console.log(timeslots);
```

Comment: But i case if i will put end time 00:00 or 00:15 func not working

Comment: Examole var startTime = "15:00" var endTime = "00:15"

Comment: I changed the code to take this case into account : just add 24

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this. It still requires additional parsing, if you want to remove seconds.

```js
function timestringToDate(time) {
  var temptime = new Date();
  var splittedtime = time.split(':');
  temptime.setHours(splittedtime[0], splittedtime[1], 0);
  return temptime;
}

var starttime = "05:45:00";
var endtime = "14:45:00";

var starttimeobj = timestringToDate(starttime);
var endtimeobj = timestringToDate(endtime);

var slotarray = [];

var slotstart, slotend;

for(var t = starttimeobj; t.getHours() < endtimeobj.getHours(); ) {
  slotstart = t.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false });
  t.setHours(t.getHours()+1);
  if(t.getMinutes !== 0)
    t.setMinutes(0);
  slotend = t.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false });
  slotarray.push(slotstart  + ' - ' + slotend);
}

slotarray.push(slotend  + ' - ' + endtimeobj.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false })); /* I add last hour */

console.log(slotarray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```